# text wrapping in two lines - recyclerview

Tags: android, textview, android-recyclerview

i am designing the app having expected UI like this

[image: Expected]

i am using RecyclerView with

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager manager=new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3,1);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

and this is the row xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding_4dp"
   >

    <com.skcsllp.mutterfly.views.widgets.MfTextView
        android:id="@+id/tagName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/textview"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_18"

        android:background="@drawable/selector_tags"
        android:textColor="@color/tags_text_color"

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

using this much i am getting the output as

[image: What i am getting]

i don't want tags to go into second line. i am aware about the fact that i have used the span count as 3 and so getting 3 tags in one line but is there any way to avoid the text wrapping in two lines?

Comment: you can add in your xml android:lines="1"

Comment: i tried that but half text goes off the layout like in case of Party animal it only shows Party

Comment: try changing the text size

Comment: that would make small each and every text small

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `RecyclerView` i would suggest you to use [AndroidTagView](https://github.com/whilu/AndroidTagView)

need to add dependency

```
dependencies {
   compile 'co.lujun:androidtagview:1.0.3'
}
```

in your main xml, instead of `RecyclerView`

```
<co.lujun.androidtagview.TagContainerLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:padding="10dp"
app:container_enable_drag="false"
app:horizontal_interval="10dp"
app:vertical_interval="10dp"
app:tag_clickable="true"
app:tag_theme="pure_teal" />
```

and in your activity/fragment

```
TagContainerLayout mTagContainerLayout = (TagContainerLayout) findViewById(R.id.tagcontainerLayout);
mTagContainerLayout.setTags(List<String> tags);
```

you will get output something like below, for more you can refer that library, they have given nice example project also.

[image]

other usefull libraries are listed below :

https://github.com/loopeer/MultiTextTagView
https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips
https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout
https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout

Comment: Thanks mate! its bunch of information in one answer. but still m not in favour of using any library for just one screen task. anyways thankx

Comment: Its upto you to use it or not, i have just given easiest way to implement your screen.

Comment: hey @Ravi could you help me out with [this](https://github.com/whilu/AndroidTagView/issues/13)

Answer (score 0):

I think , you have to write a custom ViewGroup. Using the ViewGroup's onMeasure and onLayout, Get the total width of the screen. Then measure the size of TextView. If the TextView width is less than the screen width, place the TextView. Continue to next TextView, with remaining width. If the TextView width is greater than the remaining screen width, then place the TextView at the next line. Continue this until you placed all the TextViews.

Comment: i guess i have tried that  this happens if i use the custom ViewGroup [check](http://s32.postimg.org/4tbcuk7yd/Screen_Shot_2016_05_05_at_11_59_20_am.png)

Comment: there might be some bug in your code. The TextViews must be set to singleLine/ noOfLines="1" , so that they wont wrap to second line.

Comment: will just have check since i was doing everything via code in this. there was no xml involved.

Comment: oh i was missing noOfLines in it. but still there is something to work around.[see](https://files.slack.com/files-tmb/T0468PDF1-F16AMUNP3-ec27c57609/screenshot_2016-05-05-11-57-06_1024.png) Book worm and selfie king